# UIButtons Alignment

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to implement like word cloud in my app.
[image]

The image shown is like word cloud with left alignment.

What I did was, for placing the buttons I am checking whether the width of the text is greater than total width of the screen, if it is greater place the button in next row i.e increment the y position, if it is not just place the buttons. Everything is working fine. But what I want now is , i want to move the buttons alignment, like, I want to start the first button from center of the screen. Please help me to do this...

Comment: did u look into UIStackView ?

Comment: No , i have tried to make the buttons alignment

Comment: programatically create button and add top,height,width and horizontally center constraint. this will get you the result (for first button alone). then add other buttons to the right. it will make sense.